# Dell Latitude 5580 with buttons above and below the trackpad. How can I remap them?

Tags: touchpad, laptop, hardware

This laptop has a total of 5 buttons around the trackpad: three above and two below the trackpad.

The three *above* are mapped to left, middle and right click.

The left one *below* is mapped to middle click so the lower ones definitely work, it's not a harware problem.

I want to have the left and right buttons below mapped to left and right clicks, just because that's how I've been using laptops for many years.

How do I do this in Ubuntu 22.04?

When I do `xinput` I get this:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

That doesn't seem to be enough inputs. There's nothing in the DConf Editor which seems to apply to, or even know about, these buttons, but they're working so they must be configurable somehow?

Comment: I know somebody who had success with using these instructions: https://fostips.com/remap-keys-ubuntu-22-04/
, albeit with a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I eventually used Input Remapper:

https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

which I had actually tried before and failed with.

The trick was, when I'd tried it before I'd tried to do it via the keyboard or the hotkeys. It turns out this particular button is associated with neither of them, it's actually part of the DualPoint Stick inputs. Very surprising.

Once I'd discovered that however, I hit the problem button which was returning a middle key press, and it told me I was hitting *both* the left and the right buttons below the trackpad. There was obviously something wrong in the hardware.

I added a remapping from the offending "BUTTON LEFT + BUTTON RIGHT" to "mouse" and "BTN_LEFT" and the problem was solved.

[image: Input Remapper showing how I fixed the button]